# WYSIWYG - Text and code editor

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery-plugins, tinymce, wysiwyg

I have a need, something I'm sure other developers must have and StackOverflow does have.

## Scenario

I'm building a site to post code examples on, articles that are written by me through an admin system but also possibly Front-end reg'd users.

## Mission

To have a WYSIWYG editor that a user can post articles.  Obviously it may be a paragraph of text, some headings... not a problem as TinyMCE currently handles this.
Mixed in with the text will be code examples, preferably in a code tag.

## Execution

So I have been playing with extending TinyMCE.
I can allow code tags, but cannot get it to put highlighted text into code tags, but can get it into pre tags. Not a problem.
So pasting:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="jsonObjectOrElementProperty">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text>":</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="jsonObjectProperties"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

into the WYSIWIG and highlighting and selecting Preformatted is ok, it encodes all the brackets to < and > and that is perfectly fine.  It's stored in my DB and comes out as such;

```
<pre>&lt;xsl:template match="*" mode="jsonObjectOrElementProperty"&gt;<br /> &lt;xsl:text&gt;"&lt;/xsl:text&gt;<br /> &lt;xsl:value-of select="name()"/&gt;<br /> &lt;xsl:text&gt;":&lt;/xsl:text&gt;<br /> &lt;xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="jsonObjectProperties"/&gt;<br /> &lt;/xsl:template&gt;</pre>
```

BUT when editing, so loading up the textarea with existing content; see HTML;

```
<textarea class="tinyMCE"><pre>&lt;xsl:template match="*" mode="jsonObjectOrElementProperty"&gt;<br /> &lt;xsl:text&gt;"&lt;/xsl:text&gt;<br /> &lt;xsl:value-of select="name()"/&gt;<br /> &lt;xsl:text&gt;":&lt;/xsl:text&gt;<br /> &lt;xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="jsonObjectProperties"/&gt;<br /> &lt;/xsl:template&gt;</pre></textarea>
```

TinyMCE re-encodes all the brackets and removes ALL and ANY XML based code, Script tags as non-valid elements, rather than treating them as plain text.

Add to this, that it has no-kind of CDATA functionality so that it ignores some parts...

I need a plugin, as I can't write it from scratch, I havn't the time nor budget. For what StackOverflow has exactly let me do in the creation of this question!! *Good Stackoverflow*

## Question

Has anybody had any luck with doing this to TinyMCE?
Can I steal/borrow Stackoverflows? checking the source can't see that its a plugin, more of a custom built thing.
Does anybody know of any other Formatting plugins that allow for code snippets?

Comment: Nope... This isn't a request for product suggestions. Not in the least

Answer (score 0):

[Codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) - could be a solution for you?

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at code mirror, but if you were writing something up, like you do a question on here... You wouldn't want to markup all the textual content yourself would you?

Comment: Well, that's why Stackoverflow uses Markdown syntax instead of a WYSIWYG editor...

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to adjust your tinymce init setting valid_elements and valid_children (don't forget your attributes there too).

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to have to do that for ALL possible tags... especially as XML can be ANY tag name.

Comment: deactivate the cleanup setting then

Comment: Deactivate cleanup setting? is there such a thing?!?!? Off googling...

hmmm not sure, still need to make sure it's still valid XML, as it is stored in an XML string in the DB, and output into a larger XML document at output for XSLT to convert to xHTML.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:cleanup
"it also makes sure it is a correct XHTML document, with all tags closed, the " at the right places, and things like that."

Comment: yes, there is such a thing, but if you need to make sure you still got valid html, then you shouldn't deactivate it.